# Get file size in kB or MB

Tags: powershell

I'm running the PS script to get the file size in kB/MB/GB (whatever size of the file), but I'm not getting the file size. Also how can I get the file size in another server at the same time in the same script?

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Test -rec |
    ? {! $_.PSIsContainer} |
    Select Name, @{L='Size';E={$_ | Convert-Size}}
```

```
Name        Size  
File 1.txt     
File 2.txt     
File 3.txt     
File 4.txt     
File 5.txt     
File 6.txt     
File 7.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of a file is held in the `Length` property. You can convert it by using the `1KB`, `1MB` or `1GB` literals. For example to get the size in megabytes:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Test -Recurse| 
? {! $_.PSIsContainer} |
Select-Object  Name, @{Name='Size'; Expression={[int]($_.Length / 1MB)}}
```

I've cast the result to an integer so that you get a whole number.

**Update**
To qualify the size with the units you can convert it to a string and add the prefix

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Test -Recurse| 
? {! $_.PSIsContainer} |
Select-Object  Name, @{Name='Size'; Expression={([string]([int]($_.Length / 1KB))) + " KB"}}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks. How can I get kb or mb infront of the file size please?                                                                                     Name       Size
----       ----
File 1.txt    5
File 2.txt   20
File 3.txt   23
File 4.txt   44
File 5.txt 5045
File 6.txt 2832
File 7.txt 2434

Comment: @user9749652 - See the updated answer.

Comment: lovely, thank you so much sean